# which is better in this case, return or ref

Tags: c#, return, ref

suppose i have the following group of static functions

here i sent the variable by reference:

```
public static void ProcessEmailMessage(ref string HTML)
        {
            ModifyLinks(ref HTML);
            AddFakeImage(ref HTML);
        }

        public static void ModifyLinks(ref string HTML)
        {
            //modify HTML links 
        }


        public static void AddFakeImage(ref string HTML)
        {
            //adds an image to the HTML
        }
```

and here i sent the variable by value

```
public static string ProcessEmailMessage(string HTML)
        {
            HTML = ModifyLinks(HTML);
            HTML = AddFakeImage(HTML);
            return HTML;
        }

        public static string ModifyLinks(string HTML)
        {
            //modify HTML links
            return HTML;
        }


        public static string AddFakeImage(string HTML)
        {
            //adds an image to the HTML
            return HTML;
        }
```

which one makes more sense, and is there any performance difference between the 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoid using out- and ref parameters if possible.

Methods taking ref and out parameters are more diffcult to use, you need to declare a variable to hold the result, and the semantics is a bit more diffcult to understand. The performance difference (if any) would be negligible.

The Code Analysis in Visual Studio will likely emit a warning for their use in this case.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131 for a more detailed description.

Comment: A link to an external document is good, but you should include a summary here.  SO answers should still be useful if the external link breaks.

Comment: @cdhowie: Thanks for pointing this out. I have edited the post to include a little more of a summary as well.

Answer (score 2):

There is likely to be more of a performance hit when using `ref`, as this amounts to an extra level of indirection when assigning to the variable.  However, this difference is likely to be negligible.

I would prefer the forms that return a string, as this is more illustrative of what is actually happening, and allows you to chain method calls together if you prefer:

```
return AddFakeImage(ModifyLinks(HTML));
```

With the `ref` form you *force* calling code to declare a variable, and they might not otherwise need to.  This hampers readability and increases the incidence of meaningless boilerplate code.

Comment: Technically a variable is declared in both cases, it's just a question of whether or not the programmer ever needs to know about it.  In the code sample you gave there is an implicit unnamed local variable that exists.  Now, that said, it's nice to not have to know about it, but from a performance standpoint, it's not really any different.

Comment: @Servy There will be a register when JIT-compiled, but the code example I've shown will declare one less local than the original code.  The abbreviated IL would be `ldarg.0; call; call; ret;`.  So no, there is no "additional variable," at least not until the translation to native code.  (And variables don't actually exist in native code, just registers and memory locations.  The concept of a variable is higher-level than native code.)

Comment: In both cases, whether there is a named local or not, when you get to the actual processor instruction level, both are pretty likely to be en-registered, but both could potentially be stored in some location in memory if that's not possibly.

Comment: @Servy Of course. But at that level we are no longer talking about variables. If your point is that both will have identical execution speeds and likely have exactly the same native representation, that is correct. However, my example has less to do with performance and more to do with having more options regarding coding style. I never meant to imply that my example is faster than the original example, and that level of micro-optimization would be evil were I to suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

The performance differences between the two are negligible.  It's pretty much entirely a matter of preference to syntax.

The standard conventions would involve returning a new string rather than modifying a parameter passed by reference.  There are a few occasions where it's easier to use (namely when you don't have a named variable; for example when you want to pass in the return value of a method or property instead of a field).

Answer (score 1):

Not much of a difference but I'd go with "return". Try avoiding "ref" if possible.

The reason is you wouldn't have to declare a variable before passing the result of another call and you can chain calls:

with ref:

```
string modifyMe = GetMeString();
ModifyLints(ref modifyMe);
AddFakeImage(ref modifyMe);
```

compared to return:

```
string result = AddFakeImage(ModifyLinks(GetMeString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return several objects use `ref`/`out`, if you can do it with `return` simply returning one object, use `return`.
`ref` makes your code unnecessarily obscure and produces writing overhead which is unnecessary in this case.
You should always try to keep your code simple and overviewable.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer something like a builder which does:

new EmailMessageProcessor(html).WithModifiedLinks().WithFakeImages().

So no ref arguments, and everything is encapsulated.